# Quantmod, getSymbols, Extracting Open,Close Price, Volume in R

Tags: r, dplyr, quantmod

I am trying to generate an excel file containing for each stock ticker (in column 1)  - open, close, high, low, volume. So far i extracted a list of tickers (from another excel file, column "Symbol") with the following function:

```
library(readxl)
library("dplyr")
 
stocks_data <- read_excel(file.choose())
                       
v1<-pull(stocks_data,Symbol)
```

Next i would like for each ticker in list V1 create additional columns with Open, Close, Volume etc (for last closing day only, then save it all in one excel file). Is there a quick function to accomplish that? Thank you.

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can download a list of stocks and extract the last row from each xts object.

```r
library(quantmod)
library(tidyverse)

tickers <- c('ATVI', 'TTWO')
stocks <- new.env()

ohlcva <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", 'Adjusted')


getSymbols.yahoo(tickers,env = stocks)
#> [1] "ATVI" "TTWO"


tbl <- eapply(stocks, function(.x) xts::last(.x) %>% as_tibble %>%  set_names(ohlcva)) 

tbl <- 
imap(tbl, ~mutate(.x, Symbol = .y) %>%
       select(Symbol, everything())) %>% 
  bind_rows()

tbl
#> # A tibble: 2 × 7
#>   Symbol  Open  High   Low Close   Volume Adjusted
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 ATVI    78.2  80.8  77.3  79.6 12096300     79.6
#> 2 TTWO   153.  156   152.  154.   2893500    154.

write_excel_csv(tbl, 'stock_info.csv')
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. This worked great! I realized something else, im pulling a lot of unnecessary data... Let me explain. When i create the stocks list (v1) - is there a quick way to only select tickers that have non-zero volume in "volume" column?

Comment: just found simple solution: data <- data$Symbol[data$Vol > 0] to filter out non-zero volume symbols. Thanks again!

Comment: i just noticed that its pulling 3 days old close data when putting together tbl. any idea why?